# Failing to deploy GitHub pages because of write permission

Tags: github-pages

I'm building my website forked from https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io. During the job setup, the log clearly prints:
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions:
Contents: read
Metadata: read
Pages: write
But during deployment, it still shows:
Error: Failed to create deployment (status: 403) with build version 9ffb90cf2f2dc3f0730157bdaaf35866ed4b6a35. Ensure GITHUB_TOKEN has permission "pages: write".

I tried building from Actions but that created more errors, so I'm just trying to get build from branch to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have this inside on your workflow's `job` definition :

```
permissions:
  id-token: write
  pages: write
```

See [https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs#:%7E:text=pages%3A%20write%20permits%20an%20action%20to%20request%20a%20GitHub%20Pages%20build)